# Reuse calendar button from DatePicker for custom control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Is there a way to reuse the button from the DatePicker for my custom control? Or a way to get the bitmap image from the DatePicker button?

There's information on this page about the DatePicker Style/Template:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/datepicker-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

However it makes no mention of the image used on the button. Is there somewhere else on MSDN when I can find the information?

Comment: in MS doc you linked there is DropDownButtonStyle style for button. I'm pretty sure `Path Fill="#FF2F2F2F"` with large data geomerty creates calendar image

Comment: Ah you're right. The `Path Fill` part is just the number '15' used in the icon. I didn't realize the style code is used to create the image, I assumed it would be an image. I was able to get the calendar image on the icon but it's missing the colors that's shown on the DatePicker. I'll have to figure out how to get the full image, I think I"m almost there